# Question about subgroups and Lagrange thorem

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, normal-subgroups

If $G$ is a group and $H,K$ are subgroups of $G$,
how do I prove with Lagrange Theorem, that
$$\gcd(|H|,|K|)=1⇒H∩K={e}$$
Thank you!

Comment: To be pedantic, $H\cap K=\{e\}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By Lagrange $|H \cap K|\mid |H|$  and $|H \cap K| \mid |K|$ but $|H|$ and $|K|$ are relatively prime so  $|H \cap K| = 1 \Rightarrow H \cap K  = \{e\}  $

Comment: Why $H,K$ are relatively primes? they can be 4 and 9, no?

Comment: 4 and 9 are relatively prime, gcd(4,9)=1. 4 and 9 share no common factors besides 1, which is to be relatively prime.

Comment: Why $|H \cap K|\mid |H|$  and $|H \cap K| \mid |K|$? how do you got it?

Comment: H $\bigcap$ K is a subgroup of H and K, and you can show that by checking the that it satisfies closure under products and inverses. Then Lagrange's thrm says that the order of any subgroup divides the order of the group.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Lagrange Theorem implies that $|H ∩ K|$ divides $|H|$.

Comment: How Lagrange Theorem implies it?
And how it's help me? I don't see the connection between the power of the subgroups and their elements...

Comment: If $|H|=7,|K|=5$? how those cause that $H\cap K=e$?

Comment: $H\cap K$ is a subgroup of $H$ (and of $K$). Its order divides $|H|$ (and $|K|$).

Comment: @YoavFridman: $H ∩ K = \{e\}$ iff $|H ∩ K| = 1$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $N$ be the intersection of $H$ and $K$. $N$ is a subgroup: if $a,b\in N$ then $a,b\in H$ by definition of $N$, so $ab\in H$ because $H$ is a subgroup; similarly $ab\in K$; so, by definition of $N$ $ab\in N$.

Because $N$ is a subgroup of $H$, by Lagrange Theorem $|N|$ divides $|H|$. Similarly, $|N|$ divides $|K|$. Therefore $|N|$ divides $gcd(|H|,|K|)$.

Finally, if $gcd(|H|,|K|)=1$ we have $|N|=1$, so $N$ must be the trivial subgroup ${e}$.